# A Question From Pigeon Hole Principle and Three Dimensional Tiling

Tags: combinatorics, pigeonhole-principle, tiling

**A $20×20×20$  cube is built of $1×2×2$ bricks.Prove that one can pierce it by a needle without damaging one of the bricks.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to pierce such brick in 3 places, or through the center of $2 \times 2$ square, or through one of the two sides $1 \times 2$. How many possible ways are to pierce the cube? There are 3 different directions to pierce, each should pick one of the inner points in $20 \times 20$ field, otherwise it will pierce the first brick on its way.

Comment: I need a perfect answer to this question from **Problem Solving Strategies**